# Error 10060 using Python requests library

Tags: python, python-requests

This is not a duplicate. The error message may be the same, but none of the provided solutions worked for my case.

I'm trying to get data from this url using Spyder as IDE.

http://graphs.gw.govt.nz/?siteName=Akatarawa%20River%20at%20Cemetery&dataSource=Rainfall&interval=1%20Day&Alignment=1%20Day

It can be opened with a browser but when I use requests.get method, it returns the following error:

> HTTPConnectionPool(host='graphs.gw.govt.nz', port=80): Max retries
>   exceeded with url:
>   /?siteName=Akatarawa%20River%20at%20Cemetery&dataSource=Rainfall&interval=1%20Day&Alignment=1%20Day
>
> (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))

Specifying user agent and referrer won't help.

Here's my code:

```
URL = 'http://graphs.gw.govt.nz/?siteName=Akatarawa%20River%20at%20Cemetery&dataSource=Rainfall&interval=1%20Day&Alignment=1%20Day'
urlHeaders = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8 GTB7.1 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)", 
              "Referer": "http://example.com"}
r = requests.get(URL, headers=urlHeaders, timeout=None)
```

Edit: I've tried running the code on an online python IDE and gets a 200 OK. So it may not an issue with the server.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the server is under heavy load. I have no problem to get a `200 OK` response using your code. Each requests takes around two seconds, but it finished on time.

Comment: 10060 is not a HTTP response code. I get a 200 OK from that URL, and we have no idea what the expected result would be even.

Comment: The *A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond).* error message is also not a standard HTTP error message or anything that `requests` generated.

Comment: I've duplicated this to a post that details the process needed to figure out why  you might get different responses to a `requests` request, provided that `requests` is served a different response consistently, not just sometimes.

Comment: I added [Connection Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time](//stackoverflow.com/q/26700211), I see that on Windows, the local Windows socket can throw an `OSError` with that code. Set a higher timeout.

Comment: I've tried running the code in an online IDE and does get a 200 OK.